# Ajuda com vetores em c++

Tags: c++

preciso criar um programa onde dê o menor valor e diga em que posição está, exemplo

entrada: 4

```
     5,4,3,1
```

saida:

menor valor : 1

posição: 4

até agora meu codigo está assim e não faço ideia de como continuar

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int n,i,menor ;

cin >> n;

int a[n];

for (int i = 0; i< n; i++){
cin >> a[i];
} 

for(int i=0; i<n ;i++){
if(a[i]<menor){
menor=a[i];
}
}

cout << menor << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No lugar de guardar o valor do menor guarde o índice do menor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n,i,menor ;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i< n; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    } 
    menor = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<n ;i++){
        if(a[i] < a[menor]){
            menor = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "Menor: "<< a[menor] << "\tÍndice: " << menor << endl;
    return 0;
}
```